# How to improve the time of execution of this for loop?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, count, nearest-neighbor

I have a DF called "zone" with `x` and `y` columns as integers, that can be interpreted as the position of points. I need to compute the number of first and second neighbors, and I have written this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = np.random.randint(1000,6000,size=(600000,2))
zone = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['x', 'y']).drop_duplicates()

a=[]
for i,row in zone.iterrows(): 
    x = row.x
    y = row.y
    num_1st_neigh = len(zone[(zone.x>=(x-1))&(zone.x<=(x+1))&(zone.y>=(y-1))&(zone.y<=(y+1))])-1
    num_2nd_neigh = (len(zone[(zone.x>=(x-2))&(zone.x<=(x+2))&(zone.y>=(y-2))&(zone.y<=(y+2))])-1)\
    -(num_1st_neigh)
    a.append([i,num_1st_neigh,num_2nd_neigh])
a = pd.DataFrame(a, columns = ['index','num_1st_neigh','num_2nd_neigh'])
zzz = zone.reset_index().merge(a,on='index')
```

This works good but lasts 15 s on 3K points, I have 1M points and it's stll running after 2h. Any ideas on how can I improve the execution speed?

I have read that iterrows is very slow, but I don't know how else I could do it.

EDIT: I also tried the same using SQL, but also the execution time is >2h and the query returns a timeout:

```
SELECT t0.x,
    t0.y,
    count_if(greatest(abs(t0.x-t1.x), abs(t0.y-t1.y)) = 1) num_1_neighbors,
    count_if(greatest(abs(t0.x-t1.x), abs(t0.y-t1.y)) = 2) num_2_neighbors
FROM "table" t0 
    left join "table" t1 on t1.x between t0.x -2 and t0.x + 2
    and t1.y between t0.y -2 and t0.y + 2
    and (
        t1.x <> t0.x
        or t1.y <> t0.y
    )
group by 1,2
```

Any ideas both using SQL or pandas are very welcome

Comment: 1) I would experiment with using a [kd tree](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html) to search for points. 2) Can you make this example reproducible, for example by adding a piece of code which creates random points in the same format as what you're using? Some of the advice I would give depends on details of the distribution of x and y.

Comment: edited to add the code that creates random points

Comment: Bad queries have bad performance. The SQL query will be slow unless the fields are indexed. Far more importantly though, most if not all databases have spatial extensions with spatial indexes and special ways to perform nearest neighbor queries

Comment: For Pandas, you can use GeoPandas to add spatial types and indexes. For databases, you need to check the spatial support of the database you use

Comment: can you define what you mean by a first and second neighbor? this sounds like an X,Y problem where you are asking whats wrong with an implementation to solve a problem that isnt even clearly the problem...  if you had   (1,1), (0,1), (1,0) (2,1) and (1,2) all in your data set which is the first neighbor to (1,1)?   your problem seems poorly designed and also not a good fit for a database or pandas for that matter.   Are you going to be repeatedly making said queries for different points? i'd consider building a graph instead. a quad tree approach might also work.  depends on the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`BallTree`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.BallTree.html) from `sklearn`:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree

xy = zone[['x', 'y']]
tree = BallTree(xy, metric='euclidean')
num_1st_neigh = tree.query_radius(xy, r=1*np.sqrt(2), count_only=True) - 1
num_2nd_neigh = tree.query_radius(xy, r=2*np.sqrt(2), count_only=True) - 1 - num_1st_neigh
zone['num_1st_neigh'] = num_1st_neigh
zone['num_2nd_neigh'] = num_2nd_neigh
```

From a small example:

```
# BallTree
>>> zone
     x    y  num_1st_neigh  num_2nd_neigh
0  106  115              0              0
1  118  104              0              0
2  119  114              0              0
3  108  103              0              2
4  103  101              0              0
5  110  105              0              1
6  103  104              0              0
7  102  119              0              0
8  106  105              0              1
9  111  114              0              0

# Your code
>>> zzz
   index    x    y  num_1st_neigh  num_2nd_neigh
0      0  106  115              0              0
1      1  118  104              0              0
2      2  119  114              0              0
3      3  108  103              0              2
4      4  103  101              0              0
5      5  110  105              0              1
6      6  103  104              0              0
7      7  102  119              0              0
8      8  106  105              0              1
9      9  111  114              0              0
```

Answer (score 1):

The *"quick-and-dirty"* solution could be using the classic **2D spatial hash-map** (the implementation is quite straightforward):

```
class SpatialHashMap:
    def __init__(self, power_of_two_bin_size):
        self.shift = power_of_two_bin_size
        self.bins = {}

    def _get_hash(self, x, y):
        return x >> self.shift, y >> self.shift

    def insert(self, point):
        key = self._get_hash(*point)
        if key not in self.bins:
            self.bins[key] = []
        self.bins[key].append(point)

    def get_local_points(self, bounding_box):
        min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y = bounding_box
        min_hash_x, min_hash_y = self._get_hash(min_x, min_y)
        max_hash_x, max_hash_y = self._get_hash(max_x, max_y)

        local_points = []
        for hash_x in range(min_hash_x, max_hash_x + 1):
            for hash_y in range(min_hash_y, max_hash_y + 1):
                if (hash_x, hash_y) in self.bins:
                    local_points.extend(self.bins[(hash_x, hash_y)])

        return local_points

    def restart(self):
        self.bins = {}

    def generate(self, points):
        for point in points:
            self.insert(point)
```

Then:

```py
np.random.seed(42)

data = np.random.randint(1000,1100,size=(3_000,2))
zone = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['x', 'y']).drop_duplicates()

m = SpatialHashMap(3)
for point in zip(zone.x, zone.y):
    m.insert(point)

a = []
for i,row in zone.iterrows():
    x, y = row.x, row.y

    bounding_box = x - 2, y - 2, x + 2, y + 2
    points = m.get_local_points(bounding_box)
    num_1st_neigh = sum(max(abs(x - xx), abs(y - yy)) == 1 for xx, yy in points)
    num_2nd_neigh = sum(max(abs(x - xx), abs(y - yy)) == 2 for xx, yy in points)
    a.append([i,num_1st_neigh,num_2nd_neigh])

a = pd.DataFrame(a, columns = ['index','num_1st_neigh','num_2nd_neigh'])
zzz = zone.reset_index().merge(a,on='index')
print(zzz.head())
```

This prints:

```py
   index     x     y  num_1st_neigh  num_2nd_neigh
0      0  1051  1092              0              5
1      1  1014  1071              4              4
2      2  1060  1020              4              9
3      3  1082  1086              1              6
4      4  1074  1074              1              2
```

---

Benchmark:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from timeit import timeit


class SpatialHashMap:
    def __init__(self, power_of_two_bin_size):
        self.shift = power_of_two_bin_size
        self.bins = {}

    def _get_hash(self, x, y):
        return x >> self.shift, y >> self.shift

    def insert(self, point):
        key = self._get_hash(*point)
        if key not in self.bins:
            self.bins[key] = []
        self.bins[key].append(point)

    def get_local_points(self, bounding_box):
        min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y = bounding_box
        min_hash_x, min_hash_y = self._get_hash(min_x, min_y)
        max_hash_x, max_hash_y = self._get_hash(max_x, max_y)

        local_points = []
        for hash_x in range(min_hash_x, max_hash_x + 1):
            for hash_y in range(min_hash_y, max_hash_y + 1):
                if (hash_x, hash_y) in self.bins:
                    local_points.extend(self.bins[(hash_x, hash_y)])

        return local_points

    def restart(self):
        self.bins = {}

    def generate(self, points):
        for point in points:
            self.insert(point)

np.random.seed(42)

data = np.random.randint(1000,1100,size=(3_000,2))
zone = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['x', 'y']).drop_duplicates()

def fn1(zone):
    a=[]
    for i,row in zone.iterrows():
        x, y = row.x, row.y
        num_1st_neigh = len(zone[(zone.x>=(x-1))&(zone.x<=(x+1))&(zone.y>=(y-1))&(zone.y<=(y+1))])-1
        num_2nd_neigh = (len(zone[(zone.x>=(x-2))&(zone.x<=(x+2))&(zone.y>=(y-2))&(zone.y<=(y+2))])-1)\
        -(num_1st_neigh)
        a.append([i,num_1st_neigh,num_2nd_neigh])

    a = pd.DataFrame(a, columns = ['index','num_1st_neigh','num_2nd_neigh'])
    zzz = zone.reset_index().merge(a,on='index')
    return zzz


def fn2(zone):
    m = SpatialHashMap(3)
    for point in zip(zone.x, zone.y):
        m.insert(point)

    a = []
    for i,row in zone.iterrows():
        x, y = row.x, row.y

        bounding_box = x - 2, y - 2, x + 2, y + 2
        points = m.get_local_points(bounding_box)
        num_1st_neigh = sum(max(abs(x - xx), abs(y - yy)) == 1 for xx, yy in points)
        num_2nd_neigh = sum(max(abs(x - xx), abs(y - yy)) == 2 for xx, yy in points)
        a.append([i,num_1st_neigh,num_2nd_neigh])

    a = pd.DataFrame(a, columns = ['index','num_1st_neigh','num_2nd_neigh'])
    zzz = zone.reset_index().merge(a,on='index')

    return zzz

t1 = timeit('fn1(x)', setup='x=zone.copy()', number=1, globals=globals())
t2 = timeit('fn2(x)', setup='x=zone.copy()', number=1, globals=globals())

print(t1)
print(t2)
```

Prints:

```
1.9649752220138907
0.15029849001439288
```

For `data = np.random.randint(1000,6000,size=(1_000_000,2))` the spatial hash map version returns in `44.175860428018495` seconds (on my AMD Ryzen 5700X/Python 3.10 machine)